# Deleted Contacts on WhatsApp but Chat not deleted

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, chat, sms-blocking

Someone deleted me on their contacts because I can't see their profile photo anymore. I just want to know if ever our chat box is not deleted on his/her WhatsApp app, Will he/she see changes on my profile photo or status after deleting me on his/her contacts if he kept the chat box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being able to see someone's profile picture does not mean they deleted you from their contacts. It's possible they simply removed the picture and no one can see it including you.

If the person still has the chat saved, then yes they will see your profile picture.

If you don't want someone to see your profile picture you can delete their contact, and in WhatsApp settings select that only your contacts can see your picture. Alternatively you can block that person's number and they won't be able to check your profile picture

Comment: So even if for example he/she deleted me on his or her contact list, but still have the chat logs on his or her chat section, he or she will see if I changed my profile photo or if I am online or not?

Comment: That's correct. They can open the chat with you and see your new profile and last seen

Comment: Thank you for your help!